# Blurry font issue on qt-creator-4.8.0

Tags: qt, fonts, qt-creator, blurry

I started studying QT on windows 7. But I had trouble on qt-creator 4.8.0. After I finished installing qt-creator-4.8.0, I found that certain fonts are blurry. You can see it the images below:

[image: red rects font is blurry]
[image: red rects font is blurry]

As you can see, some fonts are blurry. How can I fix it?

Note that on another computer it works fine.

when i try to use qt-creator-3.6.1,it shows black screen.the image show like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5AV1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pduP7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is an OpenGL driver issue. Probably your computer is a little bit older and the OpenGL drivers are outdated. You can try to find updates from your graphics card vendor but I'm having my doubts this will help. Changing to a Qt5 based Creator might also help.

Comment: Changing to a Qt5 based Creator might also help.    how can i do ?use other version?

Comment: Sorry about the creator version - 4.8 is the latest build with Qt5.12 - so this is no advice. I have a stale computer here and will see, if the issue exists here, too. I posted a bug report to Qt quite a while ago and back then OpenGL was identified as source to Creator being not so nice.

Comment: I try to use qt-creator-3.6.1,but it show Black screen。how can i fix it to my computer.